# Difference in List of cipher suites in FIPS mode vs NON-FIPS mode

Tags: ssl, openssl, fips

I am hoping to get some guidance on collecting list of cipher suite in tls 1.2 version in both FIPS mode vs NON-FIPS mode. So I wrote ssl client and ssl server example similar to [ssl example](https://aticleworld.com/ssl-server-client-using-openssl-in-c/).

The source code does the following

```
CLIENT: 

//Opens a AF_INET socket
SSL_library_init() to create a new SSL conn state
SSL_new() after SSL_CTX_new() with method "TLSv1_2_client_method" 
//attach SSL connection state with the opened socket.
//Send some XML request and expects output accordingly.

SERVER:
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms() to load algorithms in memory table context. 
SSL_new() after SSL_CTX_new() with method "TLSv1_2_client_method" 
Set self generated certificate/private-key in the ssl context
open a socket to listen incoming request and reply to the incoming message.
```

I compiled this code with openSSL 1.0.2e libcrypto/libssl and ran it locally. After capturing
the tcpdump, I see there are almost 86 ciphersuites negotiated by client. Now to list ciphersuites when client is running FIPS mode, I added FIPS_mode_set in "client code" after SSL_library_init() and OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms() *(I hope this sequence is fine)*. Now when I captured the tcpdump, I see no changes in ciphersuite negotiated by client.

By now, I know that there are lot of capabilities changes in algorithms in fips mode but **are there no changes observed in ciphersuite negotiated when client is running in fips/non-fips mode**. ?

Comment: Unless you are using a build that changed/patched it, the DEFAULT cipherlist in 1.0.2e has 103 entries, plus 1 for the rfc5746 SCSV -- which is in the ciphersuite _list_ but isn't a ciphersuite; did you count all list entries or only ciphersuites? You may be running in an environment where FIPS is (already) forced on, like RedHat. Does your list include any entries for Camellia (10) IDEA (1) and/or RC4 (7)?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.  I have checked with FIPS_mode() in my code before running it and when FIPS_mode() returned zero (in non-fips mode), it was sending these 86 ciphersuites. Yes, my cipher list has Camellia (like TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA ), IDEA and RC4 included.

Comment: Then you are apparently using a build modified from upstream, so unless you can point to source or _accurate_ doc for it, I can't say anything useful -- except that if it's not defective and supports and is in FIPS mode, those ciphersuites (using Camellia, IDEA, RC4) _MUST_ be omitted, plus one more I forgot last time, SEED (5 in upstream).